# My application scroll becomes very slow on battery power in windows

Tags: windows, winapi, win32gui, direct-composition

I am using DirectComposition for rendering in my win32 application. The method to achieve scroll is the usual, scroll the directcomposition surface and draw on dirty rect.

The problem I am facing is when the charger is plugged in scroll becomes super smooth but on battery power its very sluggish.Though the cpu and gpu usage are somewhat same when plugged in and when on battery. Tried to look up on internet and found that refresh rate drops on battery power. Changed the setting in intel graphics manager, output is still the same.

Can someone please help with this and how can i solve this programmatically

Comment: Direct Composition uses the GPU, so this heavily depends on the GPU vendor, if you have only one GPU. I you have two you can ask Windows to choose the card you want vs the other(s) (https://pureinfotech.com/set-gpu-app-windows-10/). You can also check Windows' Advanced Power Settings. Otherwise, there's not one single answer, it depends on your hardware, for example https://superuser.com/questions/1487069/how-to-disable-intel-display-power-saving-technology or contact the vendor.